# "Grep" to only keep lines that do not have a specific character at specific position/index?

Tags: grep

I have a text file with thousands of lines of hex values:

0x20000804

0x20001004

0x20002004

0x20004004

0x20008004
etc etc
...
(For a few thousand lines)

Is there a way to do an invert grep expression to exclude the lines with a specific character in a specific index/position?

Example: With the numbers above in a .txt file, I only want to keep the lines that DO NOT have an "8" in index/position #6

Starting with:

0x20008034

0x20000804

0x20001004

0x20002004

0x20004004

0x20008004

I should get an output of:

0x20000804

0x20001004

0x20002004

0x20004004

As these lines do NOT have the character "8" in index/position 6

Comment: Please clarify:  Is this a text file with the literal text e. g. `0x20004004`, or a binary file?

Comment: It's the literal text "0x20004004", etc

Comment: You mean position 7.

Comment: For example: "0x20008004" would be excluded from the output since the number 8 is in index 6.

Comment: No, the sixth character there is a zero.

Comment: Aren't we starting from index 0? So "0x" is index 0 &1. The next "2000" are for index 2,3,4,5, respectively. Then the next number, "8", would be index 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Grep:

```
grep -vE '^.{6}8' file
```

With Awk, using an empty field separator so each character is a field:

```
awk -F '' '$7 != "8"' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ grep -v '^0x....8' /path/to/datafile
```